# Find a real $n$ such that $10(x^m)$ equals, or at least approximates $x^n$ for $m = 1.6$

Tags: functions, exponential-function

First off, sorry for the needlessly verbose title; seems the markup doesn't support non-integer exponents (or I don't know how to properly type them).

So, my problem is as the title says, with the additional info that the range of $x$ will be the interval $[0,2.5]$

I've been quite a few years without practicing algebra or function analysis. Tried googling for online tools and didn't find any that would directly solve the problem and my math is too rusty and/or primitive (I've never dealt with non-integer exponents before) to solve this myself, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be done nicely with logarithms.

\begin{equation}
10x^n=x^m \\
\log_{10}(10)+\log_{10}(x^n)=\log_{10}(x^m)\\
n\log_{10}(x)+1=m\log_{10}(x) \\
n=\frac{m\log_{10}(x)-1}{\log_{10}(x)}=m-\frac{1}{\log_{10}(x)}
\end{equation}

Then you can just plug in values for $m$ and $x$ to solve for $n$. Note that this could be difficult around $x=1$, as the value of $\frac{1}{\log_{10}(x)}$ gets [very large](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Flog%28x%29) in this area. This makes sense, as your problem is not solvable for $x=1$ (i.e. you can't make $1^n$ equal $10$, no matter what power you use).